# How to return a dynamic html in asp.net

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to create a search result page with asp.net and jQuery. It
has to work in an AJAX manner.  What I want is that I send the page
number to server via an AJAX call and the server can return an html
block so that I can attach this html block to an area in the page in
the callback after the AJAX call.

But I don't know how to assemble the html block on the server side. Is
there a good way or some kind of engine to achieve this ?  Or should I
just hard-code it like:

```
<table><tr><td>My result</td></tr> </table>
```

and return this text to client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this - you have touched on one:

1. Return the markup directly and add it.
2. Return [JSON](http://www.json.org/), parse it using standard JavaScript methods into JS objects and:

   2.1 Generate markup in JavaScript and add it.

   2.2 Find the values in the objects and put them in the HTML.

   2.2 Use a client side template library and bind the objects.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to create html block on the server side.

```
var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
using (var writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
{
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Table);
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tr);
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);
    writer.Write("My result");
    writer.RenderEndTag();
    writer.RenderEndTag();
    writer.RenderEndTag();
}
var result = stringWriter.ToString();
```